# list friend from sql

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I am trying to echo all friends from table but not all are echoed. I put following sql:

```
$sql="SELECT user2 , user1 FROM friends 
      WHERE user1 = '$log_username' OR user2 = '$log_username' 
      AND accepted ='1' AND IsBlocked='1' ";

$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
```

and this is the table:

[image: table screenshot]

and `$log_username = mtest`, I highlight the rows where the corresponding result I didn't get. I there know there is some logic error. Please help me out for this.

Comment: You likely need to put parenthesis around your OR condition.  Something like `WHERE (user1 = '$log_username' OR user2 = '$log_username') AND ...`

Comment: `accepted`, `IsBlocked` in table set as INT ? Use `$sql="SELECT user2 , user1 FROM friends WHERE (user1 = '$log_username' OR user2 = '$log_username') AND accepted ='1' AND IsBlocked='1' ";`

Comment: I doubt *any* of those records would be returned by this query, since `IsBlocked` isn't `'1'`.

Comment: *..i highlight the rows where the corresponding result i didn't get.* So, you didn't get those 4 rows or those 4 rows you want.

Comment: Tell Fast. How much time you want to reply @user ?

Comment: thnx this works u saved me :)

Comment: thnx david for pointing out this , dont know why is still showing all results perhaps bracket was not there.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT user2 , user1 FROM friends;` 
fetch all friends user1,user2 column and after that `(user1 = '$log_username' OR user2 = '$log_username')` condition get and fetch user match with atleast one column as well as last condition filter accept always 1 and friend is blocked 0.

```
$sql="SELECT user2 , user1 FROM friends 
      WHERE (user1 = '$log_username' OR user2 = '$log_username') 
      AND (accepted ='1' AND IsBlocked='0') ";

$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation of your answer to help other users of the site. Code-only answers are not very useful and tend to be marked as low quality and potentially deleted.